# Unable to retrieve metadata , Unable to find requested .NET framework Data Provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am just learning asp.net MVC and while trying to add a new Controller I get this error:

[image]

This are the configurationg I am making:

[image]

This is my code:

```
 public class Movie {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public  class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}

<add name="MovieDBContext"
       connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Movies.sdf"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did u install Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your connectionstring, I think you are trying to connect to SQL Server CE database
Just change it regular Sql 2008 / Sql 2012 Connectionstring.

Should work

Answer (score -1):

in the connection string

```
DataSource=.\App_Data\Movies.sdf
```